# Rellenar un select con datos de una tabla

Tags: javascript, java, mysql

Rellenar una lista desplegable en base a los datos que están en una tabla de una base de datos. Quisiera saber como hacerlo si estoy trabajando java web.

```html
<select name="unidadAprendizaje" required>
  <option value="" selected="true" disabled>SELECCIONE UNA MATERIA</option>
  <option value="ADMINISTRACIÓN DE ARCHIVOS" >ADMINISTRACIÓN</option>
  <option value="ESTRUCTURA DE DATOS I" >ESTRUCTURA DE DATOS I</option>
  <option value="BASES DE DATOS" >BASES DE DATOS</option>
  <option value="ESTRUCTURA DE DATOS 2" >ESTRUCTURA DE DATOS 2</option>
  <option value="TALLER DE BASES DE DATOS" >TALLER DE BASE DE DATOS</option>
  <option value="TERMODINÁMICA" >TERMODINÁMICA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hola, Victor, las preguntas tipo ¿Como puedo hacer esto? no suelen ser bienvenidas, intenta buscar por internet y prueba lo que encuentres. De todas formas echa un vistazo a [ask] para mejorar el formato de tu pregunta

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices que estás trabajando Java Web?

Comment: Ah bueno, creo que no fui muy claro. La cuestión es que "tecnologías" usar para hacer el llenado automático, he escuchado de AJAX y JSON aunque desconozco de si existen otras formas de hacerlo.

Comment: A grosso modo tendrás que hacer toda la capa del server o consumir algún Webservices externo. Una vez que tengas eso claro puedes hacerlo con Ajax para traerte la información e iterar con JS sobre las options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se un poco mas especifico, como que tecnologías usas refiriéndose a Frameworks o manejadores que uses ya que existen muchas opciones para cada una de estas. Si estas creando una aplicación de JEE una de las formas mas sencillas seria usar [JSTL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) si usas jsp por ejemplo:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Item 1</th>
<th>Item 2</th>
<th>Item 1</th>
<th>Item 1</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="myList" items="${List}">
<tr>
<td>${myList[0]}</td>
<td>${myList[1]}</td>
<td>${myList[2]}</td>
<td>${myList[3]}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Solo es necesario agregar las librerías JSTL en tus jsp para poder usarlo.

Fuente: http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/jsp/jstl-foreach-tag.php

Comment: Si, me refería a los Frameworks que podría usar, Muchas gracias me ayudo bastante.